# shell script inside container with * as parameter value

Tags: shell, containers, kubectl

I have my script running fine on local linux bash shell. howeve it fails to run inside container bash. any hint to work around?

```
kubectl create clusterrole cluster-admin-devops --verb=* \
    --non-resource-url=* --resource=*.*
```

> the server doesn't have a resource type "*" in group "*"

The same command works when I run it locally on my linux bash shell.

failed output:

```
kubectl create clusterrole cluster-admin-devops '--verb=*' \
    '--non-resource-url=*' '--resource=*.*'
```

> the server doesn't have a resource type "*" in group "*"

Comment: I tried using "" but no help.

Comment: Try single quotes: `--verb='*'`

Comment: no luck.. tried single, double, export all=* and replace with $all, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubectl version 1.9 does not support --resource. I upgraded to 1.13 and that helped. support was added in 1.12.